# Apache LoadBalancing, sticky session, and Spring security framework

Tags: apache2, spring-security

I have a public facing Apache 2.2 webserver that I've configured to proxy and balance requests to back-end web applications deployed on Tomcat 6.0. I am using Spring FW + Spring security framework as technology stack, therefore the application is using a cookie with  jsessionid. The snippet below is from the Apache configuration:

ServerName abc.mydomain.com

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/ stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid nofailover=On scolonpathdelim=On
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/

<Proxy balancer://mycluster >
    BalancerMember http://10.179.40.165:8080/abc
</Proxy>

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

<Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

The problem is that Spring Security will redirect to invalid session url on any request after a successful login. What can I do to solve the problem?
Thanks

Peter

Comment: solved the problem by defining two directives:ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain and ProxyPassReverseCookiePath in order to have Apache re-engineer the cookies storing jsessionid

Comment: Could you write something more about usage these two directives in this specific case? I'm struggling with a similar problems and I can't find any solution.

Comment: Peter write your answer as an answer to your own question that way your question won't show up unanswered.

Comment: Hi @PetreMaierean, Could you please provide your values for this directives. As I am also facing same issue. I have tried these things, But none helped

Answer (score 0):

i just had this issue as well.

found the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9951315/1211174

here is my configuration:

```
   <VirtualHost vm1.mydomain.com:443>
         ServerName public.domain.name


         <IfModule mod_proxy.c> 
         ProxyRequests Off
         ProxyTimeout 5400

         #should be the otherway. white list instead of black list
        <Proxy *>
           Order deny,allow
           Allow from all
        </Proxy>


        <Proxy balancer://mybalancername>
               BalancerMember ajp://localhost:8209
               BalancerMember ajp://localhost:8210
               ProxySet lbmethod=bytraffic
               ProxySet stickysession=JSESSIONID
        </Proxy>


        ProxyPass / balancer://mybalancername/
        #check out http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html for more info

        ProxyPassReverse /  balancer://mybalancername/
        ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain  balancer://mybalancername  https://public.domain.name



  </IfModule>
```

seems like that with out

```
               ProxySet lbmethod=bytraffic
               ProxySet stickysession=JSESSIONID
```

spring security doesnt get the right cookie