# sticky session with apache web server and tomcat servers

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I am using apache web server as a  load balancer for two tomcat instances behind apache. When the first request goes to node A and second request from the same client goes to node B, i cant access session variables within node A. It's obvious. I surfed in the internet and found that enabling sticky sessions would help. But all the tutorials for enabling the sticky sessions in apache look confusing. Is there any simple step-by-step tutorial for this? Please help.

Code fragment from comment:

```
ProxyPass /balancer-manager ! 
ProxyPass /balancer://mycluster/ stickysession=JSESSIONID 
ProxyPassReverse /balancer://mycluster/ 
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>; 
  BalancerMember ajp://localhost:9001/ route=NodeA1000 retry=10 
  BalancerMember ajp://localhost:9002/ route=NodeB1000 retry=10 
</Proxy>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For apache httpd to keep your sessions tied to the same backend, it needs to know which cookie keeps the session ID.  For java, this is (usually) *JSESSIONID*.

If you're using the `ProxyPass` directive, use

```
ProxyPass /example http://backend.example.com stickysession=JSESSIONID
```

To be found in [the excellent apache httpd documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html).

Comment: Hi, 
Its not working. I have configured as below
`code`
ProxyPass /balancer-manager  !
ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/ stickysession=JSESSIONID
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/

<Proxy balancer://mycluster>;
  BalancerMember ajp://localhost:9001/ route=NodeA1000 retry=10
  BalancerMember ajp://localhost:9002/ route=NodeB1000 retry=10
</Proxy>
`code`

Comment: @shk: Check, using your browser, if the cookie name is correct.  It might be configured differently.  It might be lowercase.  Keep in mind that, as per documentation, you can give multiple cookie names by comma-separating them

Comment: Hi Joeri, Thanks for the help. But I cant see any cookie in the browser with the name of jsessionid( OR JSESSIONID). Do i need to make any configuration for this in tomcat/apache?

Comment: @shk: to link your request to the correct session, the server needs a key.  This is normally done through a cookie, or as part of the url.  Normally, tomcat does this automatically.  Try connecting to your tomcat without the proxy and check if your sessions work correctly, and search for the key.  This is a whole new question :)

Comment: Its working in scenarios where the server does not send 302 redirect to another server. But when my tomcat (that's behind apache) sends 302 redirect to some other standalone tomcat server, will this new standalone server overwrite the existing JSESSIONID value when req.getSession() is called?

Comment: @shk: the cookie is normally maintained per domain and path.  If your other tomcat is behind the same apache, and it's configured on the same path, it will receive the same sessionID as the first one.  It will then create a session with that ID.  If the other tomcat is not behind apache, it will create a completely new session, since it will not receive the cookie.

Comment: Hi ,please help me on this issue. stackoverflow.com/questions/22656837

Comment: Note that you may also need to set `ProxyPassReverseCookiePath`: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreversecookiepath

Comment: Is this solution is applicable to windows load balancer server?

Comment: @ManojPatil theoretically, it should work for any load balancer (conceptually).  But I doubt the syntax would be the same :)

Comment: Thanks Joeri, Actually we are using apache for load balancer and backend 2 IIS nodes, we deployed a app with windows auth. We have noticed most of time aspnet session mixed up when request served appache servers.Pls correct 
Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEIDGS=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED <Proxy balancer://mybalancer>
    BalancerMember "http://X.91:80"  route=s1
    BalancerMember "http://x.83:80"  route=s2
ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEIDGS nofailover=On
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /tapp balancer://mybalancer/tapp/
ProxyPassReverse /tapp balancer://mybalancer/tapp/

Comment: @ManojPatil it's probably a good idea to post this as a separate question.  Just just as a hint, it makes no sense to set a cookie in apache, and then use the same cookie for the session.  The session is managed by IIS (in your setup) and so you should look up what IIS is using.

Answer (score 17):

This worked for me...

Instead of using stickysession=JSESSIONID in ProxyPass directive it has to be set within balancer configuration using ProxySet stickysession=JSESSIONID:

```
<Proxy balancer://mybalancer>
BalancerMember ajp://server1:8009 route=tomcat1
BalancerMember ajp://server2:8009 route=tomcat2
ProxySet lbmethod=bytraffic
ProxySet stickysession=JSESSIONID
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /myapp/ mybalancer://myapp/
```

It was **not working** for me when I was using it in ProxyPass as shown below:

```
ProxyPass /myapp/ mybalancer://myapp/ stickysession=JSESSIONID
```

#### This should be added to apache docs, because it's such a pain to solve.

Comment: Have you found any reason why stickysession on ProxyPass could not work?

Comment: It is said in the apache docs that stickysession is available on 2.4.4 and later, maybe you have an older version running.

Answer (score 6):

Pls try this, I'm sure this will work for you.

Step-1: Add below code in httpd.conf:

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
BalancerMember http://<NODE1>/<APP>/  route=jvm1 
BalancerMember http://<NODE2>/<APP>/  route=jvm2
ProxySet lbmethod=bytraffic
ProxySet stickysession=JSESSIONID
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /<APP>/ balancer://mycluster/ 
ProxyPassReverse /<APP>/ balancer://mycluster/
```

Step-2: Add below code in server.conf:

```
a) <NODE1>
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">    
b) <NODE2>
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm2">
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem I have come across too - if you define your balancer within a vhost then it seems to use the stickysession as documented. However if you are defining a balancer outside of the vhost its used in then the stickysession gets lost so you have to set it using ProxySet within the balancer itself.

Answer (score 2):

None of the above solutions worked for me, but I found it in MOTECH project documentation here: http://docs.motechproject.org/en/latest/deployment/sticky_session_apache.html

This config works for me (on Apache 2.4.41):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    (...)
    Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
    (...)
    <Proxy balancer://mycluster>
        (...)
        BalancerMember http://10.20.30.40:8080 route=backend-1 enablereuse=On
        BalancerMember http://10.20.30.41:8080 route=backend-2 enablereuse=On

        ProxySet lbmethod=bytraffic
        ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
        (...)
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/
    (...)
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are using mybalancer where you have tu use balancer:

```
ProxyPass /myapp/ balancer://mybalancer/ stickysession=JSESSIONID
```